# cant access nested params from ckeditor gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to access a nested param put in by the ckeditor gem. I can't seem to get to them. I can access other nested params.

Here are my params:

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"token==",
 "task"=>
  {"subject"=>"(Quote Requested) LT Quote",
   "description"=>"For sample",
   "problem_on"=>"2019 June 21",
   "due_on"=>"2019 June 28",
   "job_id"=>"121",
   "lmi_host_id"=>"0",
   "assigned_to_id"=>"104",
   "priority"=>"Medium",
   "task_class_id"=>"2"},
 "task_template"=>{"title"=>""},
 "note"=>{"{:class=>\"notes\", :ckeditor=>{:language=>\"us\"}}"=>"<p>test test<strong>setset<em>testste</em></strong></p>\r\n"},
 "bill_hours"=>"0",
 "bill_minutes"=>"0",
 "nonbill_hours"=>"0",
 "nonbill_minutes"=>"0",
 "cat_type_id"=>"",
 "activity"=>{"location_id"=>"", "location_modifier_id"=>"", "review"=>"0", "telecommute"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"172330"}
```

I can access

> params[:activity][:location_id]
>   and
>   params[:task][:subject]
>   as examples.

When i try to access anything under

> params[:note]

I get nil returned.

> params[:note]

returns the following:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"{:class=>\"notes\", :ckeditor=>{:language=>\"us\"}}"=>"<p>test test<strong>setset<em>testste</em></strong></p>\r\n"} permitted: true>
```

And i need to find a way to get `<p>test test<strong>setset<em>testste</em></strong></p>\r\n`out of the params

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the client

```
{"{:class=>\"notes\", :ckeditor=>{:language=>\"us\"}}"=>"<p>test test<strong>setset<em>testste</em></strong></p>\r\n"}
```

looks very strange because this the key `"{:class=>\"notes\", :ckeditor=>{:language=>\"us\"}}"` to access the value you need! 
i think you need to check the client side why it sends it like that

Comment: Thank you so much! I will need to review the view and see what the deal is. params[:note]["{:class=>\"notes\", :ckeditor=>{:language=>\"us\"}}"] gives the value i need though